# vbscript unable to create activex component 'MSXML.DOMDocument' on Windows 2012R

Tags: xml, vbscript

I am trying to run a vbscript which shreds an XML document using the MSXML.DOMDocument.4.0 on Windows Server 2012R2 (I have tried the version free and other versions found onthe machine,3 and 6, as well).  And the script throws an error 'cannot create activex component: 'MSXML.DOMDocument.v.0' where it tries to load the dll.

1. I have tried registering the msxml3/4/6.dll from both the 32bit and the 64bit folders and still getting the same error.
2. Another article suggested using 'mmc -32' to add 'component services' to console root, then select the appropriate DCOM config object and grand acceess. However I am not sure which object need to be set with what permission in order for the VBSCript to be able to load MSXMLn.dll file.

Comment: 1) Give us the code you're trying to make work, please, and 2) explain what you mean by "shreds an XML document," as that makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `MSXML2`, not (plain) `MSXML` - e.g.:

```
Dim oXDoc  : Set oXDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.6.0")
```